# Naming convention for REST API child endpoints

Tags: api, rest, naming-conventions

Let's imaging I have a couple of related data tables (and of course objects):

```dart
class Parent {
  final int id;
}

class Child {
  final int id;
  final int parentId;
}
```

For parent CRUD actions I will use recommended naming convention:

- GET /parents - retrieve all parents
- POST /parents - create new parent
- GET /parents/:id - retrieve parent with unqique id
- PUT /parents/:id - update parent with unqique id
- DELETE /parents/:id - delete parent with unqique id

Using the same recomendations for naming conventions, I will use these requests for children:

- GET /parents/3/children - get all children for parent with id 1
- POST /parents/3 - create new child for parent with id 1
- GET /parents/1/children/3 - get the child 3 for parent with id 1
- PUT /parents/1/children/3 - update the child 3 for parent with id 1
- DELETE /parents/1/children/3 - delete the child 3 for parent with id 1

Id `3` is unique (primary key) `id` of child so I don't need to know the parent `id` in requests for fetch, update, delete of child because actually I can use names similar to:

- GET /children/3 - get the child 3 (implicitly it belongs to parent 1)
- PUT /children/3 - update the child 3  (implicitly it belongs to parent 1)
- DELETE /children/3 - delete the child 3  (implicitly it belongs to parent 1)

And attention, here it is the question! How should I organize enpoint names for children CRUD requests? Should I use the same pattern of naming as described above? Or should I combine patterns like:

- GET /parent/3/children - get children for parent 3
- POST /parent/3/children - create a child for parent 3
- GET /children/3 - get the child with id 3
- PUT /children/3 - update the child with id 3
- DELETE /children/3 - delete the child with id 3.

Answer (score 0):

REST doesn't care what spellings you use for your resource identifiers; from the perspective of a general purpose component

```
/parents/1/children/3
/children/3
/b7191775-b50b-4f35-815f-49070adbfc29
```

Are all *fine*.

If you anticipate needing to frequently describe the identifier of a parent resource from the child context, `/parents/1/children/3` may be convenient because you can trivially convert the child identifier to the parent identifier using [dot segments](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-5.2.4).

Comment: I do not anticipate the issue when `3` is identifier of child which does not belong to parent `1`. Taking `3` as child identifier to get info from database will work for any parent identifier. And as for me it is wrong. To fix this issue I need to check if child identifier belongs to parent scope before getting child info. But is makes functionality more complex because I need to execute excessive SQL query to check if child is belong to parent. So the question of naming is related to this problem.